# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification found versions 25.3.1

Tags: android

[image: the error i am getting]

This question has been answered many times but i still cant figure out how to fix it. I am getting error in this line in build.gradle     `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` . I dont know what do i need to add in my build.gradle in order to make it work.I got a full tree of dependencies but i dont know what do i need to change or how to do it

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 (*)
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
    |         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 (*)
    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0
    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0
    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:10.2.0
    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (*)
    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0
    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (*)
    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0
    |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (*)
    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 (*)
    +--- com.sromku:simple-storage:1.2.0
    +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
    +--- at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3
    +--- it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11
    |    +--- com.github.markushi:android-ui:1.2
    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3 -> 25.3.1 (*)
    +--- project :android-pdf-viewer
    |    \--- com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.5.0
    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 25.3.1 (*)
    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0
         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0
              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (*)
              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
              \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.2.0
                   +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (*)
                   +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.0
                   |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0 (*)
                   |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
                   +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.0 (*)
                   \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0 (*)
```

Comment: what is the max api level  you are using ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 15      targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the exact error message that you are getting. It should be more than what you have in your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be the problem of your pdf library.

```
+--- project :android-pdf-viewer
|    \--- com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.5.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 25.3.1 (*)
```

It still use the support library v4 version 21.0.3.

You can try upgrade the pdf library to 1.7.0

```
\--- com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.7.0
 \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
```

Or specify support v4 version to `25.3.1` manually in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```